# Why are more particles showing in the render than in the viewport?

Tags: particles

There is quite a difference between the 3D View and the render. In the viewport there are a few palm trees but when I hit 'Render' I can see a huge amount of trees that looks like a forest. I have no children setting activated.

[Blend File (Palm Trees)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aow569HuUBdhodvxI7UPP_Yk4IDWvUD5)

3D viewport:

[image]

Render:

[image]

Any solution as to what's going on and why there are so many particles (trees) shown?

Comment: Please remember to use https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend files.

Comment: @RayMairlot yeah but i was getting error there so i uploaded to drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your particle system is set to only show 10% of the total particles.

In the 'Display' panel of the particle system change the 'Display Percentage' to 100%:

[image]

This will display all the particles in the viewport.